# Passing String array as a parameter to JUnit test

Tags: java, arrays, junit, junit4, parameterized

I'm using @Parameter for Field injection while writing a JUNIT test. Is it possible to pass a String array to the data object[][]. I mean in the below code
can I pass a string array like this

```
{"Input1","Input2",  {"file1","file2"}}
```

Code Snippet

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class AModuleTest {

@Parameters
public static Iterable<Object[]> testData() {

    Object[][] data = new Object[][]{
        {"Input1","Input2",  }
    };
    return Arrays.asList(data);

}

@Parameter(value=0) public String tabName;
@Parameter(value=1) public String fileSetName;
@Parameter(value=2) public String[] fileNames

@Test
public void ATest(){
//here I'm just passing those parameters to these functions clickTab, Navigate()...
    clickTab(tabName); 
    Navigate(fileSet);

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured that we can create an array within arrays; by creating a String array within the data Object like

```
 Object[][] data = new Object[][]{
    {"Input1","Input2", new String[] {"file1", "file2"} }
};
```